# How to receive posted array data from model to resource API controller using CURL in Laravel?

Tags: php

I'm building API for Laravel and I want to send array of data using CURL from model to resource API controller.

Model

```
$curl = curl_init();
$headers = 'X-CSRF-Token:'.$token;

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $path,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $action,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($course_data),
    //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>$course_data,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=> $headers,
    // CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(

    //     // 'Accept: application/json',
    //    'headers' => $headers

    // ),
));
```

API Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{      
    $courses = Course::insert($request['course_data']);
    return CourseResource::collection($courses);
    // dd($action);
}
```

Comment: What is in your Request? Is it empty?

Comment: Yes @DamianDziaduch

Comment: @DamianDziaduch what i want is array data in controller which i have sent from model but i am getting a blank page.

Comment: what does your curl return?

Comment: @Lublaut it returns $course_data(which contains array data).